# Google Maps in modal not showed after two times open - Ionic

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm created a Google Map in a modal view, once I'm open that modal, the map was showed. Then, I clicked nav-back-button to go to main page. After that I tried to open the modal to view the map again, but the map didn't showed.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/aishahismail/pen/vLZprV

**HTML:**

```
   <script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <div class="modal">
        <header class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">I'm A Modal</h1>
          <div class="button button-clear" ng-click="modal.hide()"><span class="icon ion-close"></span></div>
        </header>
        <content has-header="true" padding="true">
          <p>This is a map</p>
          <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
        </content>
      </div>
    </script>
```

**Javascript: Controller**

```
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function($ionicModal) {
        $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
    }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });  

  $scope.showMap = function (){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

        //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
        var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
        var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: compiled[0]
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        $scope.map = map;
  }

  $scope.openModal = function(){
    $scope.modal.show();
    $scope.showMap();
  }
});
```

I found the same question in stack overflow  [Google maps in modal only displays first map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656144/google-maps-in-modal-only-displays-first-map) but still didn't got the answer. I've been looking it in 1 day, but I'm still cannot solve this problem. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Have you tried reading this Stack Overflow ticket? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037272/google-map-not-showing-on-bootstrap-modal

Comment: Also, try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532411/google-map-not-filling-modal-popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 1 week sitting try to find the solution, finally I've got the answer.

All the code is same stated in the questions, but I'm only add this in my **controller**. Check it out

```
//Remove modal
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $scope.modal.remove();
});

//Set $scope.map to null
$scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.map = null;
    });
});
```

I'm also change the maps module code, I'm used $cordovaGeolocation. Below is full code for homeTabCtrl

**Javascript: homeTabCtrl**

```
 .controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $cordovaGeolocation) {

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function($ionicModal) {
        $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
    }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });  

     $scope.showMap = function (){
        var options = {
           timeout: 10000,
           enableHighAccuracy: true
        };

        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function (position) {

          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

          var mapOptions = {
             center: latLng,
             zoom: 15,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

          google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function () {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: $scope.map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: latLng
            });
        });

        }, function (error) {
           alert("Could not get location");
        });
    };

    $scope.openModal = function(){
      $scope.modal.show();
      $scope.showMap();
    };

    //Remove modal
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
    });

    //Set $scope.map to null
    $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            $scope.map = null;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Moving the code to a mainCtrl instead of HomeTabCtrl resolve the issue:

check this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/vLZaWg)

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
...
```

**JS:**

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $compile) {
// the code previously in HomeTabCtrl
}
```

I noticed that you are using an old version of Ionic and also old-style directives.
Here is a version updated of Ionic app using [Angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps):

http://plnkr.co/edit/n4Qr3OMcGIb5uU28xISU?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, can I know is there have any other solution because if I apply it to other projects, that project have the controller that required value: 

`.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $compile) { 
     
     if($rootScope.gender == 'Male'){ 
           //Do something
     };

    ..................
 }` 

Based on the situation above, of course it will return the error because $scope.gender is undefined. 

I'm edit it in this http://plnkr.co/edit/e5dUjauCZNdxA1psQ4Ej?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find "gender" in any part of the code posted in your question above...

Comment: Sorry for that, this http://plnkr.co/edit/e5dUjauCZNdxA1psQ4Ej?p=preview the new one.

Comment: Please could you explain more precisely what's the problem? In particular in the Plunker I haven't seen anything strange...

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confuse right now trying to solve this problem since 2 days ago.  Okay, I will explain it clearly. 

What I'm trying to do is I want to display "$scope.test" in "modal.html", but it didn't showed. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/e5dUjauCZNdxA1psQ4Ej?p=preview

You can see at the header of "modal.html" displayed like this "Output: ". It should be "Output: Test" just like in "map.html".

Comment: Ok, the problem is related to inheritance of scopes: the modal inherits the scope from 'mainCtrl'. So you have to set $scope.test = "test"; in this controller and not in the 'MapTabCtrl'. But also this controller inherits the scope form 'mainCtrl', so test property is shared among view controllers and modal. Is that ok?